# System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement' cannot be converted to Boolean

Tags: vb.net

I have a error in vb.net. //Update: I'm changed the code.
How can i put this vale (*Answer*) to vb.net application?
`<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="*Answer*" class="regular-text">`

```
Private Sub WebBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser2.DocumentCompleted
    Dim elementcollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser2.Document.All
    For Each element As HtmlElement In elementcollection
        If element.GetAttribute("classname").Contains("username") Then
            MetroLabel3.Text = element.InnerText
        End If
        If element.GetAttribute("value").Contains("first_name") Then
            bilgi2.Text = element.InnerText
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The If-Then statement requires an expression that produces a Boolean.  GetElementById() returns HtmlElement, not Boolean.  The snippet doesn't make enough sense to have a guess at what you intended.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think

```
WebBrowser2.Document.All
```

returns the type you're expecting.

Comment: You may be right, but I don't think that answers the question.

Comment: You're right. The correct answer is Hans Passant's comment, I think